# Bash tar append file

Tags: bash, tar

How to append file to tar, e.g. file located in `/usr/file.txt`?

I want to append it in tar to `var/file.txt` for future extract it into `[tar location]/var/file.txt` instead of `[tar location]/usr/file.txt`, using the

```
tar --append --file foo.tar bar
```

Is it possible to put file in tar this way without replacing `/usr/file.txt` to `/var/file.txt` before archiving?

Comment: Just Make a backup and give it a try !!

Comment: I think it's not so dangerous)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to use a symlink `var/file.txt -> /usr/file.txt`.

```
mkdir var && ln -s /usr/file.txt var
tar --dereference --append --file foo.tar var
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GNU tar, there's a `--transform` option for that, which takes a sed-like expression as argument:

```
tar --append --file foo.tar --transform='s,^usr/,var/,' /usr/file.txt
```

Comment: I am on Mac OS X 10.6, so transform option in not supported